# In PowerShell Form.Show() does not work right, but Form.ShowDialog() does

Tags: winforms, powershell, modal-dialog

I am trying to display an image via powershell. I made a [script](https://gist.github.com/969855) based on [this forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/202216-display-image-powershell.html).

If I use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) it works fine, except the powershell execution stops while the dialog is up. However, that is by design for a modal dialog. If I call [Form.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) in PowershellISE the form shows up, but freezes and cannot be moved or dismissed. Behavior is similar if I copy and past the code to a powershell console.

How do I make the dialog non-modal, and not freeze.

Comment: Show() might not be a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192558/why-does-a-form-displayed-by-powershell-sometimes-not-show-up

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**First Answer Why it appends.**

In a Windows graphic program the thread which create a Window must loop in a message pump in order to redistribute (translate) messages coming from the user action to events in his Windows.

In a modal window, the modal code that handles the window display runs its own message pump loop and doesn't return until the window is closed.  That's why the code after `ShowDialog()` won't execute until the window is closed.

`Show()`, just ask to show the Window, but if there is no pump loop to manage the messages coming from user action, it just freezes.

**Second a simple way to have two threads**

The CmdLet start-job use another thread from the pool allocated by Powershell so it makes the dialog non-modal, and it does not freeze.

```
function goForm
{
  [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

  $file = (get-item 'C:\temp\jpb.png')
  #$file = (get-item "c:\image.jpg")

  $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($file);

  # This tip from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358372/windows-forms-look-different-in-powershell-and-powershell-ise-why/3359274#3359274
  [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
  $form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
  $form.Text = "Image Viewer"
  $form.Width = $img.Size.Width;
  $form.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
  $pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
  $pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
  $pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height;

  $pictureBox.Image = $img;
  $form.controls.add($pictureBox)
  $form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
  $form.ShowDialog()
}

Clear-Host

start-job $function:goForm

$name = Read-Host "What is you name"
Write-Host "your name is $name"
```

Comment: Ok, for you, knowledge is a sausage, and it's better to keep people ignorant ... you are the architect ...

Comment: x0n What about "that kind of question" makes you think I don't care how the Sausage is made? Yes, in the end I do need to GTD, so in the short term I need start-job or show-ui. However, understanding the "why" helps me evaluate whats going on here.

Comment: This doesn't work. The thread goForm doesn't show any window, because it's not on the main-thread...

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is actually to not block the interactive console when an image is shown then you still can use the script as it is with `ShowDialog` but you should start it using, for example, [`Start-Job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347692.aspx). Thus, the dialog is still modal but it blocks execution in another runspace. The main runspace still can be used for invoking other commands.

Caveats: 1) You should close all opened dialogs before closing the interactive console. 2) If you care, you should remove completed jobs yourself (when a dialog is closed a job that started it still exists).

I use a similar approach in my custom host and it works fine. I also tested it with the script from your link. I changed it slightly so that it is called `show-image.ps1` and accepts a file path as a parameter.

This command shows an image and blocks the calling runspace:

```
show-image.ps1 C:\TEMP\_110513_055058\test.png
```

This command shows an image and does not block the calling runspace:

```
Start-Job { show-image.ps1 $args[0] } -ArgumentList C:\TEMP\_110513_055058\test.png
```

Comment: According to you remark, I just realise that stop-job or remove-job seems to hang on jobs with this king of function. Do you experience the same thing ?

Comment: `Stop-Job` finishes only when a dialog has closed. `Remove-Job` works fine after closing a dialog and fails "cannot remove the job ... because the job is not finished" if a dialog is still opened.

Comment: `Remove-Job -Force` works but it also "waits" for dialog exit.

Comment: Roman, it seems that when the window closes the jobs state becomes "Completed". So when is it necessary to call Stop-Job? is that when you close powershell/powershellISE while the window is opened?

Comment: `Stop-Job` is not needed (besides, it is not quite effective, as we can see). `Remove-Job` might be needed if you care of completed (their windows are closed) jobs that still exist and consume some resources.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @JPBlanc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986829/2060966), this would also be possible (and faster) using a runspace.

Here's a basic example (the rest would basically remain the same)

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
[void]$ps.AddScript({
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  $form = [Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
  $form.ShowDialog()
})
[void]$ps.BeginInvoke()
```