# Powershell: Unable to interact with Form stored in a .Net Assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I'm just trying to learn this thing and in future, wanted to use it in one of my projects.

I have a small Form with a simple Text box, stored in a .Net dll (C#). And here is my class in this dll which contains methods to interact with this Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static Form1 dlg = new Form1();

        public static void ShowForm()
        {
            dlg.ShowIcon = true;
            dlg.Show();

        }

        public static void SetText(string MyText)
        {
            dlg.Text = "Form Text ";
            dlg.SetText(MyText);

        }
    }
}
```

Successfully loaded this form by referencing this dll into another C# application while calling its method i.e.:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassLibrary1.Class1.ShowForm();
}
```

And I was able to interact with the form perfectly.

Now loading same in Powershell using:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\Playing\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll")
[ClassLibrary1.Class1]::ShowForm()
```

Now this is loaded successfully at its default position, but I can't interact with this form i.e. I can't type in its Text Box, neither I can move or even close this form by clicking on its Close (x) button on right corner. Whenever I put my mouse on it, it becomes a HourGlass i.e. waiting for some process .

To verify if form is not hanged, I called SetText at Powershell prompt:

```
[ClassLibrary1.Class1]::SetText("String from Powershell")
```

and it worked fine. TextBox received this text properly, but still I can't interact with the form with my mouse.

I feel, I have to manually set its Window Handler i.e. System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window.
But I don't know which Handler and how to achieve this?

Please guide .... Would really appreciate for any alternative tricks.

Comment: Did you try to _run_ it with Application.Run() instead of Form.Show()? I feel it should do everything in the proper way to use forms from a console application.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(dlg) would Show form as a Modal dialog and I can't interact with Powershell, until I close the form.

Comment: But you can't use Form.Show() because it has not a message pump to use. I would use ShowDialog() (or Application.Run()) in a separate thread (using BeginInvoke inside SetText() function).

Comment: @Adriano: Suggest you redo your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Adriano: Purpose of this application to display a Dialog with controls like Text Box, and then pass Text messages to display in that Window. If I use ShowDilog() or Application.Run(), that would prevent me issuing commands in Powershell. Can you please tell me more about BeginingInvoke inside SetText()? Thanks

Comment: @Richard THank you, I posted an answer to explain that little bit better.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed I posted an answer. Code example is pretty naive (I wouldn't write that in production) but it illustrates a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't show a form from PowerShell using `Form.Show()` method because it needs a message pump (and it's not provided by PowerShell host process).

Here what you can do to solve this issue:

- Use `Form.ShowDialog()` or `Application.Run()`, your form will have its own message pump.
- It'll be modal then you need to run it in another thread. I suggest to use a background thread and `BeginInvoke()` in your `SetText()` method.

Here code to do that (I won't change your code too much so I'll keep it as a singleton instance even if this prevents to display form multiple times). Code is just an example (I wouldn't suggest to use Thread Pool for this task) to illustrate the procedure.

```
public static void ShowForm()
{
    if (dlg != null)
        dlg.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { dlg.Dispose(); }));

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
    {
        Application.Run(_dlg = new Form1());
    });
}

public static void SetText(string text)
{
    _dlg.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { dlg.SetText(text); }));
}
```

In this way `Form1` will be modal in another thread (with its own message pump)  and your calling PowerShell thread won't be stopped. Communication between them is still possible via message dispatching (`Invoke()`/`BeginInvoke()`).

Please note that `SetText()` is now asynchronous, to make it synchronous just replace `BeginInvoke()` with `Invoke()`.

Comment: Do you have any info about writing Ps cmdlet in C# and use winform interaction, as there should be a message pump already?

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed I saw your message just now...anyway message pump is given by two things: Application.Run() or Form.ShowDialog(). Even if you write a C# cmdlet it won't have any message pump by itself.

Comment: yes you are right. A week ago, I experimented with a sample application and got same result. Also, experimented with ShowUI (https://showui.codeplex.com/). It is doing what I want, but do not provide enough documentation to adopt it.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed I didn't know that project. It looks OK but, what a pity, source code isn't available!

Comment: Ahh.. I guess, source code is not available due to some System Outage problem. I only found absence of documentation.