# Run Powershell script from Powershell asynchronously without a second visible Powershell window? Or use Form.ShowDialog()

Tags: powershell

I have a moderately complex power-shell script called status.ps1 which creates a new window using a System.Windows.Forms
This "Display Computer Status" window shows the results of various commands.  The script is based on a [technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Display-computers-status-c8ff289d) sample

My problem is that when I run it from powershell with just "status"  the powershell window waits for it to exit before I can type the next command as shown here - which I would like to "fix"
[image: run script does not return]

I believe the following summarise the problem code which causes the suspension as it can be run from powershell window and get the same behaviour

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form1.ShowDialog()
```

The last line causes the suspension if I replace it with

```
$form1.Show()
```

then none of the buttons are enabled and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192558/why-does-a-form-displayed-by-powershell-sometimes-not-show-up/2194396#2194396) which seems applicable however using the suggested

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form1)
```

Gives

`Exception calling "Run" with "1" argument(s): "Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid         operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead."                                                                                At C:\Users\ross\OneDrive\Ross\cmds\bin\status.ps1:461 char:2                                                           +     [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($form1)                                                                   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                               + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException`

Which says to use what I am trying to remove

So I have tried running the application asynchronously
with "START-PROCESS powershell -ArgumentList Status" this allows me to continue to use the original powershell window but I get a second powershell window as shown

[image: 2nd Window]

Is there a way to start the the whole script asynchronously without showing a second power-shell window?
Alternatively if I can run just the Form.showdialog that would be ok as well

I have not found any articles which match my needs exactly I'm on Windows 10

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: You mean like `Start-Job` to run it asynchronous? Same logic could be applied using runspaces.

Comment: gees that was easy...  Start-Job -ScriptBlock { status }

Comment: @Abraham, that's worth writing up as an answer, given that it's non-obvious and given that `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` does _not_ work.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, I only have access to my phone at the moment so it would have to wait.

Comment: yes - if you do I shall mark it as an answer .  I have a follow up question - about how to get the code to respawn itself - I believe it is a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279909/pass-command-line-arguments-on-to-to-self-but-with-start-job