# Pass command line arguments on to to "self" but with Start-Job

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

At [Asynchronous start][1]  I had a question about starting a power-shell script  asynchronously which creates a form.  As answered in that question this can be solved using start-job
eg
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test NW -NoWarning -Paranoia:2 }

So I have tried to write the Test.PS1 script routine so it re-calls itself with "Start-Job Test -NoSpawn"  The switch nospawn then means it runs without a second call. I have tested this with the example code the above line now has to be and it works

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test NW -NoSpawn -NoWarning -Paranoia:2 }
```

However I'm struggling to get the parameters from the original command line  to passthrough to the job
I have tried creating a string in the correct format , an array , list the arguments manually , I either get repeated arguments being passed or all of the string ending up in the first Parameter $ComputerList  -

A summary of the parameters and the attempts are

```
 Param ([string]$ComputerList = 'status\edi.csv',[switch]$NoSpawn,[switch]$NoWarning,[switch]$Debug,[INT]$Paranoia=6)
...... <Snip>
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $ComputerList -NoSpawn -NoWarning:$NoWarning -Paranoia:$Paranoia }
```

Doesn't work due to scope  - also switches are wrong way to do this

```
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test -NoSpawn $Args } -argumentlist $ComputerList
```

Insufficent arguments but works  - But I think One Argument is possible ?

```
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $Args -NoSpawn } -argumentlist @("-NoWarning:$NoWarning","-ComputerList:$ComputerList","-Paranoia:$Paranoia")
```

Everything ends up in $ComputerList

```
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $Args -NoSpawn } -argumentlist "-NoWarning:$NoWarning -ComputerList:$ComputerList -Paranoia:$Paranoia"
```

Everything ends up in $ComputerList

Full code follows

```
Param ([string]$ComputerList = 'status\edi.csv',[switch]$NoSpawn,[switch]$NoWarning,[switch]$Debug,[INT]$Paranoia=6)

$Log_Paranoia=$Paranoia
If ($Debug) {   $debugPreference="Continue"}    #enable debug messages if -debug is specified
If ($NoWarning) {   $WarningPreference="SilentlyContinue"}  #turn off warning messages

function Write-Paranoid($Level, $message) {
    $CS=Get-PSCallStack
    $Caller = $CS[1]
    $Module = "$($Caller.FunctionName)[$($Caller.ScriptLineNumber)]"
    $Diff=$level - $Log_Paranoia
    $MSG= "$Module($($Level),$($Log_Paranoia)):$message"
    if ($level - $Log_Paranoia -le 0 ) {   
        Write-host $MSG
    }
    if($Error.Count -gt 0 ) {
        $MSG= "$Module($Level)ERROR:$Error[0]"
        Write-Error $MSG
    }
    $error.clear()
}
Function AddStatusBar($form , $Txt) {
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Enter"
    $statusBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar
    $statusBar.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $statusBar.TabIndex = 4
    $statusBar.Size = SDS 428 22
    $statusBar.Location = SDP 0 337
    $statusBar.Text =  $Txt
    $form.Controls.Add($statusBar)
    $statusBar
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Exit"
}

Function Create-Form ($Title)
{
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Enter"
    $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form1.Text = $Title
    $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $form1.ClientSize = SDS 890 359
    $form1.StartPosition = 0
    $form1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,185,209,234)
    $form1
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Exit"
}

Function GenerateTestForm
{
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Enter"
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    $Form1 = Create-Form "Test Form"
    $Alist = Get-CommandLine
    $StatusBar = AddStatusBar  $form1 $AList
    $form1.ShowDialog() | Out-Null # Suspends calller
    Write-Paranoid 10 "Exit"
}

if ($NoSpawn )
{
    Write-Paranoid 3 " NoSpawn "
    Write-Paranoid 5 "Call GenerateForm"
    if ($Test) {
        GenerateTestForm
    } else {
        GenerateTestForm
    }
} else {
    Write-Paranoid 3 "NOT NoSpawn restarting as job"
# note that test.ps1 is in the path so it will restart this script
    # Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $ComputerList -NoSpawn -NoWarning:$NoWarning -Paranoia:$Paranoia } #Wrong scope  
    # Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test -NoSpawn $Args } -argumentlist $ComputerList  # Insufficent aruments but works  - ONLY One Argument possible  - 
    # Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $Args -NoSpawn } -argumentlist @("-NoWarning:$NoWarning","-ComputerList:$ComputerList","-Paranoia:$Paranoia") # Everything ends up in $ComputerList
    # Start-Job -ScriptBlock { test $Args -NoSpawn } -argumentlist "-NoWarning:$NoWarning -ComputerList:$ComputerList -Paranoia:$Paranoia" # Everything ends up in $ComputerList
    
}
```

Comment: You can pass `$PSBoundParameters` to the Job's scope and then call this function using those bounded parameters, but it's not clear what this `status` function is. The Forms code in the question is irrelevant in this case

Comment: status displays something in a form  it uses a showDialog hence the need for a start-job . In this test code the form is just used to display the command arguments -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

- How can I re-invoke the script at hand as a background job, passing all original arguments (parameter values, including *default* parameter values) through?

A simplified example:

```bash
param (
  [string] $ComputerList = 'status\edi.csv',
  [switch] $NoSpawn,
  [switch] $NoWarning,
  [switch] $Debug,
  [int]    $Paranoia=6
)

if ($NoSpawn) { # already running as a background job.

  "I'm now running in the background with the following arguments:"
  $PSBoundParameters

} else {  # must re-invoke via a background job

  # Add *default* parameter values, if necessary, given that 
  # they're *not* reflected in $PSBoundParameters.
  foreach ($paramName in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys) {
    if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($paramName)) {
      $defaultValue = Get-Variable -Scope Local -ValueOnly $paramName
      if (-not ($null -eq $defaultValue -or ($defaultValue -is [switch] -and -not $defaultValue))) { 
        $PSBoundParameters[$paramName] = $defaultValue 
      }
    }
  }

  # Start a background job that reinvokes this script with the original
  # arguments / default values.
  Start-Job {
    $argsHash = $using:PSBoundParameters
    & $using:PSCommandPath -NoSpawn @argsHash
  } | 
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

}
```

Note:

- For demonstration purposes, the initial call *waits for the re-invocation via a background job to finish*, using [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) `-Wait -AutoRemoveJob`
- In your real code, you can simply discard `Start-Job`'s output (a job-information object) with `$null = Start-Job { ... }`, and then rely on the job getting cleaned up when the caller's session as a whole exits.
- The extra code needed to propagate parameter *default values* is somewhat cumbersome, but necessary, given that the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) does *not* reflect default values.

  - [GitHub issue #3285](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285) discusses this limitation, and suggests a potential future solution.

Comment: Correct enough ...  I needed to add if ($key -ne "NoSpawn") in the loop otherwise I got the error "Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'NoSpawn' is specified more than once. ..."  but otherwise the other switch parameters pass through correctly and so does the string parameter

Comment: oh and thanks for $using:PSCommandPath - which ensures the script is restarting itself - rather than some of my edits where I had to keep changing from the scripts

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem, @Ross. I didn't notice the issue, because I tested in PowerShell _Core_, which now tolerates specifying a parameter value _both_ via splatting _and_ as a separate argument, with the latter taking precedence. In Windows PowerShell, you get an error. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @Ross, on second thought I've revised the fix to now categorically exclude `$null` values and `[switch]` parameters that default to `$false` (they should never be given a default of `$rue`, but it is technically possible).